# How to enable MultipleNavigationMenu permission?

Tags: deployment, tab, navigation, cicd

I'm trying to extract the **NavigationMenu** metadata from Salesforce so I can deploy the Object tabs on the Navigation Bar via one of the Salesforce CI/CD tools.

One of the support agents told me I require the "**MultipleNavigationMenu permission**" as stated in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_navigationmenu.htm

Navigating into System Administrator profile, I have checked under **System Permissions** and **App Permissions** with no luck finding that specific permission. Help?

Comment: if you're admin, then from workbench you can retrieve navigationmenus without additional permission.(Atleast it did not require any additional permission for me to retrieve navigation menu by means of Workbench and package.xml)

Comment: I tried doing that but got the error `Entity Type 'NavigationMenu' is not available in this organization` using version 52.0